# Sort by one element in list of lists of fixed size and remove doubles

Tags: python, sorting, double

I would like to find the best way to achieve this. (I already can do it manually but i am looking for a librairy that do this directly).

I want to sort a list of lists based on the first index and remove doubles of first index.

```
sections = [
    [1, 4, 1],
    [5, 3, 2],  # Sort on the first element of sublist
    [2, 2, 3],
    [2, 1, 4],  # Double to remove
]

assertion = [
    [1, 4, 1],
    [2, 2, 3],
    [5, 3, 2],
]

def sort_first_and_remove_double(sections):
    
    return result


assert sort_first_and_remove_double(sections) == assertion
```

The goal is to not coding any loop directly but do it in one or two lines using librairies, for optimisation reasons, my datas are huges.

My attempt code is here:

```
def sort_first_and_remove_double(sections):
    sections = remove_double(sections)
    sections = sort_sections(sections)
    return sections


def sort_sections(sections):
    ids = get_ids(sections)
    return [x for _, x in sorted(zip(ids, sections))]


def remove_double(sections):
    ids = get_ids(sections)
    keeped_sections = []
    for i, id_check in enumerate(ids):
        ids_keeped = get_ids(keeped_sections)
        if id_check not in ids_keeped:
            keeped_sections.append(sections[i])
    return keeped_sections


def get_ids(sections):
    return [section[0] for section in sections]
```

But it is very slow!

Edit: Here an update of times:

```
t0 = time.perf_counter()
sort_first_and_remove_double(lst)
print(time.perf_counter() - t0)  # 7.719699351582676e-05 s
t0 = time.perf_counter()
list(dict(map(lambda x: [x[1][0], x[1]], sorted(enumerate(lst), key=lambda pair: (pair[1][0], -pair[0])))).values())
print(time.perf_counter() - t0)  # 7.587004802189767e-06 s
t0 = time.perf_counter()
sorted(dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x), lst[::-1])).values())
print(time.perf_counter() - t0)  # 3.0700030038133264e-06 s
```

Comment: `[2, 1, 4]` Is the double of what exactly? Also you need to add your current approach, people need to benchmark their solutions against yours

Comment: The double is based on the first element wich is `2` in this example.

Comment: Asking for recommendations is also off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you wont solution like this?

```
sorted({x[0]: x for x in sections[::-1]}.values())
```

or without for

```
sorted(dict(map(lambda x: (x[0], x), sections[::-1])).values())
```

Comment: @VincentBénet, try variant with generator. I think that it more effective than realization with map.